# Can I change one instance variable with a radio_button inside a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

My intention is to use a radio button to change the value of an instance variable I can't do it. I'm using this radio_button_tag code:

```
<%= form_for(@cig) do |f| %>
 <h3>
  <%= f.radio_button :pack_id, 9 %>
  <%= f.label :pack_id_my, "From MY pack" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :pack_id, 2 %>
  <%= f.label :pack_id_gift, "From a GIFT pack" %>
</h3>
<h3><%= @cig.pack_id %></h3>
```

I want to change the value of pack_id according to the radio button selected but I don't know how to access to the variable. I've tryied with radio_button_tag also but I could not do it.

```
<%= form_for(@cig) do |f| %>
 <h3>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:pack_id, 9, true, checked ? @cig.pack_id = 9) %>
   <%= label_tag(:pack_id_my, "From MY pack") %>
   <%= radio_button_tag(:pack_id, 2) %>
   <%= label_tag(:pack_id_gift, "From a GIFT pack") %>
 </h3>
 <h3><%= @cig.pack_id %></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this simple code;

```
<%= form_for(@cig) do |f| %>
    <h3>
      <%= f.radio_button :pack_id, Pack.last.id %>From <strong>MY</strong> pack
      <%= f.radio_button :pack_id, 2 %>  It's a <strong>GIFT</strong> cig
    </h3>
.
.
.
```

You must, only, to nest the radio button in your form. That's all. 
Is necessary to put the same variable name. Like this the radio_button method will choose between the two options. If you change the variable name; the methos will allow you to choose the two options. don't forget to include, in the controller, your instance variable in your strong params method:

```
  def cig_params
    # *Strong params*: You need to *whitelist* what can be updated by the user
    # Never trust user data!
    params.require(:cig).permit(:date, :minutes, :pack_id)
  end
```